# ruby hash array value changes when assigned array value changes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

im trying to find all possible sums using numbers from the testArray. i am assigning arrays to a hash, it uses sum as key and stores the integers from testArray that add up to the sum:

```
testArray=[1,2,3,4]
@possibleSums=Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }
  for j in 0..testArray.size-1
    tmpSum=0
    output=""
    @sumArray=[]

    for k in j..testArray.size-1
        tmpSum=tmpSum+testArray[k]
        output=output+"+"+testArray[k].to_s
        @sumArray.push(testArray[k])
        @possibleSums[tmpSum]=@sumArray
        p output+"="+tmpSum.to_s
    end
  end
```

the problem is that i noticed that as @sumArray changes through every iteration of the loop, the previous recorded hash key value also changes. what am i doing wrong?

example:

```
output: "+1=1"
@sumArray: [1]
@possibleSums: {1=>[1]}
output: "+1+2=3"
@sumArray: [1, 2]
@possibleSums: {1=>[1, 2], 3=>[1, 2]}
output: "+1+2+3=6"
@sumArray: [1, 2, 3]
@possibleSums: {1=>[1, 2, 3], 3=>[1, 2, 3], 6=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

you can see that value of key 1 and 3 kept changing with @sumArray

Comment: You are putting a reference to `@sumArray` in the hash.

Comment: red_menace is right .. you can use `@possibleSums[tmpSum]=@sumArray.clone` instead

Comment: A more Ruby-like way to obtain an array of all sums for `test_array=[1,3,7,10]` is as follows: `require 'set'; (1..test_array.size).each_with_object(Set.new) { |n,st| test_array.combination(n).each { |a| st << a.sum } }.to_a #=> [1, 3, 7, 10, 4, 8, 11, 13, 17, 14, 18, 20, 21]`. I wrote `test_array` rather than `testArray` because, by convention, Ruby uses [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for names of variables and methods.

Comment: so @possibleSums[tmpSum]=@sumArray.clone is the proper way to assign instance of an array to a hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting a reference to @sumArray in the hash. –
red_menace
Sep 12 at 17:48

red_menace is right .. you can use @possibleSums[tmpSum]=@sumArray.clone instead